# AsterixDB error when joining geometry: Cannot invoke \"org.apache.hyracks.control.nc.io.FileHandle.close()\" because \"fHandle\" is null"

Tags: sql

I am attempting to use AsterixDB (which uses SQL++) to join two sets together via an sql query. In one dataset, I have a series of points in the form of latitude and longitude. The other dataset is geometries for zip codes. I am trying to append the relevant zip code to the first dataset based on whether the point exists in the zip code or not.

The query is below as well as the schema for each dataset

```
use csv;

select sett.lat, sett.long, zip.g
from csv_set as sett
left join csv_zipset as zip
on st_contains(zip.g, st_make_point(sett.lat, sett.long));
```

```
create type csv_type as {
    id:uuid,
    ...
    lat: double,
    long: double
};
```

```
create type csv_ziptype as {
    id: uuid,
    g:geometry
};
```

This is the error I am facing:

```
ERROR: Code: 1 "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.apache.hyracks.control.nc.io.FileHandle.close()\" because \"fHandle\" is null"
```

I have tried adding null checks for both the point and geometry with no luck.
I have also validated that st_make_point is working properly, and st_contains works when I pass it a fixed geometry which leads me to believe that this is an issue with the geometry.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: have you checked if teh hardrive is full? also try to reduce the number of rows affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exhausting more options I came to the realization that there were multiple types in my dataset: polygon, multipolygon, linestring, and geometryCollection. It seems that AsterixDB doesn't yet have the ability to compute st_contains with geometry collections. Once I removed those entries from the dataset the query was able to complete successfully.